# How do I specify my own icons so they show up in a Google Endpoints API discovery document?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I've tried to get the icons section to contain my own icons, rather than google search ones by trying to monkey patch `ApiConfigGenerator.get_descriptor_defaults`.  Unfortunately these are ignored/discarded when the discovery document is finalized.

```
{
 "kind": "discovery#restDescription",
 "etag": "...",
 "discoveryVersion": "v1",
 "id": "acme:v1",
 "name": "acme",
 "version": "v1",
 "description": "Acme API",
 "ownerDomain": "google.com",
 "ownerName": "Google",
 "icons": {
  "x16": "http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/search-16.gif",  # <-- acme icon url here!
  "x32": "http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/search-32.gif"   # <--
 },
 "protocol": "rest",
 "baseUrl": "http://acme.appspot.com/_ah/api/acme/v1/",
 "basePath": "/_ah/api/acme/v1/",
 "rootUrl": "http://acme.appspot.com/_ah/api/",
 "servicePath": "acme/v1/",
 "batchPath": "batch",
 "parameters": {
```

How do I work around this, if at all?

Comment: Great question @sstriker. Looking into it right now :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported yet in the `google.appengine.api.endpoints` library but is possible if you specify `icon16` and `icon32` in the API config. To do this, you can monkey patch the `pretty_print_config_to_json` method on the `ApiConfigGenerator` class, or subclass it and monkey patch the class in the `google.appengine.ext.endpoints.api_config` module.

For example, we import the module and save the original class before monkey patching the module:

```
import json
from google.appengine.ext.endpoints import api_config
OriginalConfigGenerator = api_config.ApiConfigGenerator
```

Then we define a subclass to replace it:

```
class NewConfigGenerator(OriginalConfigGenerator):
```

and then override the method which produces the API config:

```
  def pretty_print_config_to_json(self, services, hostname=None):
    descriptor = super(NewConfigGenerator, self).pretty_print_config_to_json(
        services, hostname=hostname)
    descriptor = json.loads(descriptor)
```

once you have the config dictionary, you can add your own keys and return it:

```
    descriptor['icon16'] = 'YOUR-16x16-ICON-LINK'
    descriptor['icon32'] = 'YOUR-32x32-ICON-LINK'
    # This will be slower than overwriting __api_descriptor
    # due to the json.parse/json.loads having to occur twice
    # but hacking around private methods is a pain.
    return json.dumps(descriptor, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

and finally, be sure to monkey patch the module before actually creating an API:

```
api_config.ApiConfigGenerator = NewConfigGenerator
```

This could be done, for example, by putting this monkey patch in a file like `monkey_patch.py` and then using

```
import monkey_patch
```

in the file where your API classes are defined. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @bossylobster; I should have made my question more complete, as the monkey patch was something that I had.  The gem in there is using 'icon16' and 'icon32'.  I had falsely inferred the following by looking at the eventual discovery document:

    descriptor['icons'] = {
      "x16": "http://example.com/s/16x16_transparent.png",
      "x32": "http://example.com/s/32x32_transparent.png",
    }

Comment: Indeed. The API config mapping is usually different from the Discovery Document. I'm happy to field more types of questions as you come up with them. We're hoping to document the API config in full so this is easier to just do.