# Is it possible to add a description to the Cloud Endpoint fields in the API Explorer?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have seen this in the Google API's. Is it possible for Cloud Endpoints as well?

[image]

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/adexchangebuyer/v1.2/adexchangebuyer.accounts.get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally possible. We've had some StackOverflow posts about monkey patching and this would be another prime example.

For example:
[How do I specify my own icons so they show up in a Google Endpoints API discovery document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532502)

For this case, the content served at `/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs` contains your API config and the "description" you want here is for a "parameter".

So for example in the method

```
@endpoints.method(MySchema, MySchema,
                  path='myschema/{strField}', name='myschema.echo')
def MySchemaEcho(self, request):
  return request
```

the field `strField` is a path "parameter" and so in the API config we would see

```
{
  ...
  "methods": {
    "myapi.myschema.echo": {
      ...
      "request": {
        ...
        "parameters": {
          "strField": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

To get your description in there you would need to add it to the dictionary listed under `strField` so that it reads

```
          "strField": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Most important field that ever was."
          }
```

Comment: is there a more elegant solution than this?